# $T$ is an isometry iff $T^*$ is an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm doing an exercise:

> Let $E$ and $E_1$ be Banach spaces, and suppose $T\in\mathscr{B}(E,E_1)$, i.e. $T$ is a linear bounded operator. Prove that $T$ is an isometry iff $T^*$ is an isometry. Here an isometry is required to be surjective.

It's easy to show that if $T$ is an isometry then $T^*$ is an isometry without the assumption that $E$ and $E_1$ are complete.

I am able to prove the other direction when $E_1$ is only n.v.s. I'm not sure my proof is correct. Is the completeness of $E_1$ necessary for this exercise? Or even the completeness of $E$ is also unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $E_1, E$ is needlessly confusing, lets look at operators $T:X\to Y$ instead.

Suppose $T^*: Y^*\to X^*, y^*\mapsto y^*\circ T$ is an isometric isomorphis. In that case
$$\|T(x)\|_{Y}=\sup_{y^*\in Y^*,\|y^*\|≤1}|y^*(T(x))|=\sup_{y^*\in Y^*,\|y^*\|≤1}|T^*(y^*)[x])|$$
Now $T^*$ is a bijection from the unit ball in $Y^*$ onto the unit ball in $X^*$, so:
$$\|T(x)\|_{Y}=\sup_{x^*\in X^*,\|x^*\|≤1}|x^*(x)|=\|x\|_X$$
Now suppose there exists a $y\in Y$ so that $y$ is not in the image of $T$. At this point we use the fact that $X$ is complete, since $T$ is an isometry the image of $T$ must be closed.

Define a linear map:
$$y_\lvert^*:\mathrm{span}\{y\}\oplus \mathrm{im}(T)\to \mathbb C, \quad y_\lvert^*(\lambda y+T(x))=\lambda$$
The continuity of this map follows from (is actually equivalent to) $\mathrm{im}(T)$ being closed. With Hahn Banach extend it to a continuous map $y^*$ on all of $Y^*$. But from contstruction $T^*(y^*)=y^*\circ T = 0$ and $T^*$ is not injective.

Comment: You haven't shown that $T$ is an isometry, only that it has norm $1$.

Comment: @Aweygan of course you are right. Brainfart. I fixed it.

Comment: Why can't $T^*$ be surjective? Since $T$ is an isometry, $T$ is injective. So if you suppose $T(x_1)=T(x_2)$, then $x_1=x_2$. And I'm wondering if there is an example that $X$ is not complete, and $T^*$ is a surjective isometry, but $T$ is not surjective?

Comment: Yes, you are right, from before I had it in my mind that isometry meant $\|T\|=1$ which would not have implied injectivity. This way the part on injectivity is superfluous.

Comment: As to a counter example, look at the the finite sequences with $\ell_1$ norm and the inclusion of this into $\ell_1$. The dual of both spaces is $\ell_\infty$ (since the first space is dense in the second) and the adjoint map is the identity.